# Why machine is no longer available to logon remotely after logoff

Tags: windows-xp, remote-access, login

XP machine on a domain. Have given remote access to two users, so they logoff of their sessions when complete. When they do, the machine is not pingable and will not respond to anything but a console logon. A physical restart never makes it available without a console logon first.

What have I missed in the setup for this? It is new behavior and used to not be an issue.

Comment: Anything in the log files?

Comment: nothing yet. It is as if the nic isn't initialized or something and no communication is happening

Comment: Is there a wireless NIC at play here? How about 802.1x authentication?

Comment: nope just a wired connection

Comment: The checkbox requiring Ctrl+Alt+Del for users in the User Manager. Could this be applying to remote users? I am 2000 miles away from this machine, so it is hard to just try things without locking myself out.

Comment: checked on a VM that checkbox appears to not apply

Answer (score 2):

This is behaving exactly like the network isn't turned on unless the user is logged in. I've seen this happen with some Wireless configs, as the agent that handles Wifi login is a userspace systray app which doesn't run as a service. This kind of thing is starting to show up on *wired* configs in networks that do Network Access Control. Client-side AV may put the machine into firewall deny-all mode when a user isn't logged in, which is another area to look into.

Comment: I will look at AV. One of these users does have very limited access to a single directory on the network. If they logoff would that limited access persist prior to a new logon?

Comment: That sort of thing is at a few layers above what I'm talking about, so should have no impact either way.

Comment: I admit I don't know where to look. Since I see nothing listed on the domain controller events log,for the machine or user, I am assuming no policy is prohibiting the login. Is this something to look at on local policy for this machine?